# change password based on changing hash value

Tags: php

How to update my password using hash based on this code? Let say I want my new password to be "test123" without quote. How can I generate this hash and put into this array in order to login successfully?

```
<?php

    class AuthenticationService
    {
      static $users = array( );

      static function authenticate($user, $pwd)
      {
        $user = strtolower($user);
        //var_dump(self::$users);
        if (array_key_exists($user, self::$users))
        {
            //echo "user found </br>";
            if (self::$users[$user][1] == sha1(self::$users[$user][0].$pwd))
                return(true);
            else
                return(false);
        }
        return(false);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Unless you're an expert in the field, don't roll your own password hashing function. There's no need: PHP has password_hash() and password_verify() for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$users` array is an associative array between usernames and salt+hash:

```
static $users = array( 
    "testing" => array("0a1e5dd121178b2f780622e5fbd926d5","d190c655a6f85d48ff6c1981d61e938fd147580b"),
        ^                           ^                                       ^
    username                       salt                                 sha1 hash
);
```

The code checks passwords by getting the SHA1 hash of both the passed in password `$pwd` concatenated with the salt associated with the username.

```
static function authenticate($user, $pwd)
{     
    ...
    ...
//                      dot operator concatenates salt & password
                                                             V
    if (self::$users[$user][1] == sha1(self::$users[$user][0].$pwd))
        return(true);
    else
        return(false);

    ...
}
```

In order to add new accounts for testing, you can:

1. Think of a new username & password
2. Think of a salt, can be anything (i.e, `"apple"`, `"fish123"`, `"im a complicated hash"`)
3. Get the SHA1 of the salt+password
4. Add them to the `$users` array.

As an example:

```
// new username = "fish"
// new password = "ilikephp"
// new salt     = "UwU"
// Then:

static $users = array( 
    "testing" => array("0a1e5dd121178b2f780622e5fbd926d5","d190c655a6f85d48ff6c1981d61e938fd147580b"),
    "fish" => array("UwU", sha1("UwU"."ilikephp")),
                                     ^
                    order of concatenation matters: salt + pasword
);
```

---

So what is a **salt**? Since I'm not an expert myself, I'll just leave this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). Note that in Wikipedia's example, the hash is calculated in reverse order, password+salt instead of salt+password.

Comment: My bad. My first answer was entirely wrong. I corrected my post now. @JongwooKim